# How to detect PLUS key on different language keyboards in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard

I am trying to detect when the plus key is pressed, which on my UK keyboard is positioned on the EQUALS key, but on my German keyboard on another key. I want to be able to detect the plus key without the user pressing SHIFT in case the plus sign is normally reached by shift+another key.

This is the way a normal zooming operation works in for example a browser. How do I do this in JavaFX without having a list of every single keyboard and corresponding key where plus is positioned?

For example, the program below (checking for KeyCode.PLUS) does not work on my UK keyboard. I am using JDK 1.8.0_40.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane());
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
                System.out.println("YES");
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to work on all platforms and keyboard layouts you need the raw character and a KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED Filter. From the [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) Documentation:

> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the
> platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode
> character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about
> character input. In the simplest case, a key typed event is produced
> by a single key press (e.g., 'a').

But be aware of:

> Often, however, characters are produced by series of key presses
> (e.g., SHIFT + 'a'), and the mapping from key pressed events to key
> typed events may be many-to-one or many-to-many.

Mixing them can get to a pretty ugly and hard readable code.

So your Example should look like this:

#### UPDATE

I've changed the event to KEY_PRESSED and make your example (Ctrl + '+') try to work, even if code is equal or character is equal. In most of the cases it works with the code, but sometimes the charCombo fit.

I've tried the following code with english (UK), france, german, spanish keyboard layout and it works.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCharacterCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(), 300, 300);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            KeyCombination charCombo = new KeyCharacterCombination("+", KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
            KeyCombination codeCombo = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.PLUS, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (charCombo.match(event) || codeCombo.match(event)) {
                    System.out.println("Zoom in");
                }
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks NwDx, but it still does not answer my question. I am aware that I can get the actual character pressed, but I want it to work by just hitting the *key* that the plus is on (without any potential shift (see question..)). This is how all browsers etc work in combination with the control key when zooming. And it should work for all different types of keyboards. I really think this should be possible somehow without going through the world's all keyboards manually in the code, checking what key the plus sign is on.

Comment: @j18434 I don't know if this is possible without asking for all possibilities. This is why the abstraction of KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED was introduced. How do you think the language abstraction in your OS works? It takes all the keys and give them a meaning, this is why language switching in for ex. Windows works. The Key you pressed and that signal which is passed to your OS is such a low level where JavaFX maybe never come to.

Comment: You might be right, that this is info is just not available. And I for sure have found no way of doing this. But so many programs use exactly that, ctrl+ for zooming, independent of whether shift has been pressed or not, and independent of keyboard layout. Maybe somebody can either explain how to do this, or prove it is impossible without going through all keyboard types in the universe..

Comment: @j18434 I've updated my answer and modified a bit the code. Maybe this will be a working solution.

Comment: Thanks @NwDx, that really seems to work! KeyCharacterCombination was the key concept!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your program and the working combination is to test for:

- [`KeyCode.ADD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#ADD): this corresponds to the `+` key on the numpad;
- [`KeyCode.EQUALS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#EQUALS): this corresponds to the `=` key, since you do not want the user to press `Shift`.
- [`KeyCode.PLUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#PLUS): this corresponds to the `=` key when caps are locked.

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane());
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
                System.out.println("YES");
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tunaki, this is the workaround I use myself, but I wanted this to work independent of keyboard language/layout (see question), which is my problem.